# How can finite numbers work? (dependent types)

Tags: agda, dependent-type, idris

I'm interested in dependently typed languages. Finite numbers seem very usable to me. For example, to safely index fixed-size arrays. But the definition is not clear for me.

The data type for finite numbers in Idris can be the following: (And probably similar in Agda)

```
data FiniteNum : Natural -> Type where
  FZero : FiniteNum (Succ k)
  FSucc : FiniteNum k -> FiniteNum (Succ k)
```

And it seems to work:

```
exampleFN : FiniteNum (Succ (Succ Zero))
exampleFN = FSucc FZero -- typechecks
-- exampleFN = FSucc (FSucc FZero)  -- won't typecheck
```

But how does this work? What does k mean? And how come that the type checker accepts the first implementation and rejects the second?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think about the index as an *upper bound* for any number that can be represented by `Fin n`. For example, `Fin 4` contains all natural numbers less than `4`. Here's a data declaration:

```
data Fin : ℕ → Set where
```

How does the definition relate to this? The definition of natural numbers has two parts: `zero` and `suc`; for `Fin`, we'll call those `fzero` and `fsuc`.

With our upper bound interpretation, `fzero` can be given any upper bound as long as it is not `zero` (0 ≮ 0). How do we represent that the bound can be anything other than `zero`? We can force that simply by applying `suc`:

```
fzero : {k : ℕ} → Fin (suc k)
```

This gives us precisely what we need: no-one can write `fzero` in such a way that its type is `Fin 0`.

Now the `fsuc` case: we have a number with some upper bound `k` and we want to create a successor. What can we tell about the upper bound? It surely increases by at least one:

```
fsuc : {k : ℕ} → Fin k → Fin (suc k)
```

As an exercise, convince yourself that all numbers less than `n` can be represented by `Fin n` (in only one possible way).

---

How does the type checker accept one and reject another? In this case it's simple unification. Let's take a look at this code:

```
test : Fin (suc (suc zero))
test = ?
```

When we write `fsuc`, Agda has to figure out the value of `k`. To do that, it takes a look at `fsuc` constructor: it constructs a value of type `Fin (suc k)` and we need `suc k = suc (suc zero)`; by unifying these two, we get that `k = suc zero`. So next:

```
test = fsuc ?
```

Now, the expression following `fsuc` (represented by `?`, a *hole*) has a type `Fin (suc zero)` (since `k = suc zero`). When we fill in `fzero`, Agda tries to unify `suc zero` with `suc k₂`, which of course succeeds with the solution `k₂ = zero`.

If we decide to throw in another `fsuc`:

```
test = fsuc (fsuc ?)
```

Then using the same unification as above, we get that the type of the hole must be `Fin zero`. So far this type checks just fine. However, when you try to stuff `fzero` in there, Agda has to unify `zero` with `suc k₃` - no matter the value of `k₃`, `suc` of something can never be `zero`, so that fails and you get a type error.

---

Another representation of finite numbers (that is arguably less plesant to work with) is a pair of natural number and a proof that it is less than the bound.

```
open import Data.Product

Fin' : ℕ → Set
Fin' n = Σ ℕ (λ k → k < n)
```

The original `Fin` can be thought as a version of `Fin'` where the proof is baked directly into the constructors.

Comment: It is more convenient for me to think about "what can be the type of fsuc (fzero)" than to thing about "what expressions can be of type Fin (suc (suc zero))"

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the FiniteNum Zero type is empty, because both constructors return FiniteNum indexed with a non-zero natural number. Now try to answer the following: how many elements does FiniteNum (Succ Zero) have? How do they look like? Repeat for 2,3,4...