# How do I build a list with a dependently-typed length?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

Dipping my toe into the waters of dependent types, I had a crack at the canonical "list with statically-typed length" example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

-- a kind declaration
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data SafeList :: (Nat -> * -> *) where
    Nil :: SafeList Z a
    Cons :: a -> SafeList n a -> SafeList (S n) a

-- the type signature ensures that the input list has at least one element
safeHead :: SafeList (S n) a -> a
safeHead (Cons x xs) = x
```

This seems to work:

```
ghci> :t Cons 5 (Cons 3 Nil)
Cons 5 (Cons 3 Nil) :: Num a => SafeList ('S ('S 'Z)) a

ghci> safeHead (Cons 'x' (Cons 'c' Nil))
'x'

ghci> safeHead Nil
Couldn't match type 'Z with 'S n0
Expected type: SafeList ('S n0) a0
  Actual type: SafeList 'Z a0
In the first argument of `safeHead', namely `Nil'
In the expression: safeHead Nil
In an equation for `it': it = safeHead Nil
```

However, in order for this data-type to be actually useful, I should be able to build it from run-time data for which you don't know the length at compile time. My naïve attempt:

```
fromList :: [a] -> SafeList n a
fromList = foldr Cons Nil
```

This fails to compile, with the type error:

```
Couldn't match type 'Z with 'S n
Expected type: a -> SafeList n a -> SafeList n a
  Actual type: a -> SafeList n a -> SafeList ('S n) a
In the first argument of `foldr', namely `Cons'
In the expression: foldr Cons Nil
In an equation for `fromList': fromList = foldr Cons Nil
```

I understand why this is happening: the return type of `Cons` is different for each iteration of the fold - that's the whole point! But I can't see a way around it, probably because I've not read deeply enough into the subject. (I can't imagine all this effort is being put into a type system that is impossible to use in practice!)

So: How can I build this sort of dependently-typed data from 'normal' simply-typed data?

---

Following @luqui's advice I was able to make `fromList` compile:

```
data ASafeList a where
    ASafeList :: SafeList n a -> ASafeList a

fromList :: [a] -> ASafeList a
fromList = foldr f (ASafeList Nil)
    where f x (ASafeList xs) = ASafeList (Cons x xs)
```

Here's my attempt to unpack the `ASafeList` and use it:

```
getSafeHead :: [a] -> a
getSafeHead xs = case fromList xs of ASafeList ys -> safeHead ys
```

This causes another type error:

```
Couldn't match type `n' with 'S n0
  `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
      a pattern with constructor
        ASafeList :: forall a (n :: Nat). SafeList n a -> ASafeList a,
      in a case alternative
      at SafeList.hs:33:22
Expected type: SafeList ('S n0) a
  Actual type: SafeList n a
In the first argument of `safeHead', namely `ys'
In the expression: safeHead ys
In a case alternative: ASafeList ys -> safeHead ys
```

Again, intuitively it makes sense that this would fail to compile. I can call `fromList` with an empty list, so the compiler has no guarantee that I'll be able to call `safeHead` on the resulting `SafeList`. This lack of knowledge is roughly what the existential `ASafeList` captures.

Can this problem be solved? I feel like I might have walked down a logical dead-end.

Comment: You'd better be getting a compile error; your code is unsafe!  `getSafeHead []` is ill-defined.  Ask yourself: where do you guarantee that the list is non-empty?

Comment: @luqui What about if I had `data NonEmptyList a = NEEnd a | NECons a NonEmptyList a` and my `getSafeHead` took that as a parameter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Never throw anything away.

If you're going to take the trouble to crank along a list to make a length-indexed list (known in the literature as a "vector"), you may as well remember its length.

So, we have

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where -- old habits die hard
  VNil :: Vec Z a
  VCons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

but we can also give a run time representation to static lengths. Richard Eisenberg's "Singletons" package will do this for you, but the basic idea is to give a type of run time representations for static numbers.

```
data Natty :: Nat -> * where
  Zy :: Natty Z
  Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)
```

Crucially, if we have a value of type `Natty n`, then we can interrogate that value to find out what `n` is.

Hasochists know that run time representability is often so boring that even a machine can manage it, so we hide it inside a type class

```
class NATTY (n :: Nat) where
  natty :: Natty n

instance NATTY Z where
  natty = Zy

instance NATTY n => NATTY (S n) where
  natty = Sy natty
```

Now we can give a slightly more informative existential treatment of the length you get from your lists.

```
data LenList :: * -> * where
  LenList :: NATTY n => Vec n a -> LenList a

lenList :: [a] -> LenList a
lenList []        = LenList VNil
lenList (x : xs)  = case lenList xs of LenList ys -> LenList (VCons x ys)
```

You get the same code as the length-destroying version, but you can grab a run time representation of the length anytime you like, and you don't need to crawl along the vector to get it.

Of course, if you want the length to be a `Nat`, it's still a pain that you instead have a `Natty n` for some `n`.

It's a mistake to clutter one's pockets.

**Edit** I thought I'd add a little, to address the "safe head" usage issue.

First, let me add an unpacker for `LenList` which gives you the number in your hand.

```
unLenList :: LenList a -> (forall n. Natty n -> Vec n a -> t) -> t
unLenList (LenList xs) k = k natty xs
```

And now suppose I define

```
vhead :: Vec (S n) a -> a
vhead (VCons a _) = a
```

enforcing the safety property. If I have a run time representation of the length of a vector, I can look at it to see if `vhead` applies.

```
headOrBust :: LenList a -> Maybe a
headOrBust lla = unLenList lla $ \ n xs -> case n of
  Zy    -> Nothing
  Sy _  -> Just (vhead xs)
```

So you look at one thing, and in doing so, learn about another.

Comment: This is very nice, I like the way `Natty` allows us to construct a unique value corresponding to a certain `Nat` type. How would a language with more sophisticated dependent types, like Idris, handle the "`Natty n`-for-some-`n`" annoyance? Or would we still have this problem in such languages? Is there any way to avoid 'throwing away' the value of the `n` type parameter?

Comment: In Idris, (Vec is spelt Vect and) you could use the return type `Sigma Nat (\ n => Vect n a)` to indicate that you want both the length and the vector available at run time, or you could use `Exists Nat (\ n => Vect n a)` to indicate that you want the length to be erased at run time (although the type checker knows it). In both cases, the length is an ordinary `Nat`, and you don't need two copies of it to have it both at run time and in types.

Comment: Is the underlying reason this is awkward because Haskell doesn't have a type-level lambda?

Comment: Not really (although that introduces clunkiness in other ways, but helps type inference). The problem is that there's currently no neat way to say "this info lives both at run time and in types". We're trying to fix that: it's a lot less damage than type-level lambda.

Comment: @pigworker, why do you need a `Natty` in the `unLenList` function (and `headOrBust` correspondingly)? `unLenList :: LenList a->(forall n. Vec n a->t)->t; unLenList (LenList xs) k = k xs` and `headOrBust lla = unLenList lla $ \xs -> case xs of ...`. Also, could you give an example, that illustrates why the `Natty` datatype is useful? Extracting a `Nat` from it is still O(n), and at the type level you already have `n` in `Vec n a`. You could extract an element of `Natty` from some `Vec`-related computation and use it in some `Vec`-unrelated computation, but this doesn't look like a common case.

Comment: @user3237465 In the case of vectors, of course you can recover the length of a vector which you possess by measuring it again, and of course it's annoying that `Natty n` is not the same as `Nat`. `Natty` becomes vital when it represents the length of a vector which we do not possess but intend to construct: consider writing `replicate` or `take` for vectors. You had no choice but to inline vhead, but with length info, the choice exists. Safe head may not be the finest example of analysing run time copies of indices to allow the invocation (not the inlining) of a function, but the o.p. did ask.

Comment: Ah, I was asking wrong question. I meant, why do you need `Natty` in the definition of `LenList`? It's clear, that you can grab a run time representation of the length, but what can you do with this length, that doesn't have O(n) complexity anyway? You can't convert `Natty` to `Nat` in O(1) and using `Natty` in the `replicate` function is obviously O(n). What have you achieved with this inlining? And correspondingly, why do you need `Natty` in the `unLenList` function, while you already have its ornamented version — `Vec`? You can make your recursion directly on `Vec`. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It is indeed the case that `unLenList` will tell us the length of a list which we certainly possess, and we can operate on the vector with the same computational complexity but less abstraction than on its length. The same will not be true for every indexed type. Indeed consider defining the recursive type family RVec :: Nat -> * -> *; RVec Z x = (); RVec (S n) x = (x, RVec n x). In that setting, you cannot pattern match on the vector unless you know its length. In ornamental terms, RVec captures just what extra information a list contains, relative to its length.

Comment: "but less abstraction than on its length" — I don't see the loss of abstraction. You can define `vlengthNat :: Vec n a -> Natty n` and use it just like it was used before. With the same complutational complexity, thanks to laziness.

Answer (score 6):

In

```
fromList :: [a] -> SafeList n a
```

`n` is *universally* quantified -- i.e. this signature is claiming that we should be able to build a `SafeList` of any length from the list.  Instead you want to quantify *existentially*, which can only be done by defining a new data type:

```
data ASafeList a where
    ASafeList :: SafeList n a -> ASafeList a
```

Then your signature should be

```
fromList :: [a] -> ASafeList a
```

You can use it by pattern matching on `ASafeList`

```
useList :: ASafeList a -> ...
useList (ASafeList xs) = ...
```

and in the body, `xs` will be a `SafeList n a` type with an unknown (rigid) `n`.  You will probably have to add more operations to use it in any nontrivial way.

Comment: Even better, `fromList` could compute the singleton value for the length at the same time, in case it turns out to be useful.

Comment: Thanks! I have written a follow-up question in the original post. It may turn out to be what you meant by "You will probably have to add more operations to use it in any nontrivial way."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dependently typed functions on runtime data, then you need to ensure, that this data doesn't violate encoded in type signatures laws. It's easier to understand this by an example. Here is our setup:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Natty (n :: Nat) where
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)

data Vec :: * -> Nat -> * where
  VNil :: Vec a Z
  VCons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (S n)
```

We can write some simple functions on `Vec`:

```
vhead :: Vec a (S n) -> a
vhead (VCons x xs) = x

vtoList :: Vec a n -> [a]
vtoList  VNil        = []
vtoList (VCons x xs) = x : vtoList xs

vlength :: Vec a n -> Natty n
vlength  VNil        = Zy
vlength (VCons x xs) = Sy (vlength xs)
```

For writing the canonical example of the `lookup` function we need the concept of [finite sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726164/how-can-finite-numbers-work-dependent-types). They are usually defined as

```
data Fin :: Nat -> where
    FZ :: Fin (S n)
    FS :: Fin n -> Fin (S n)
```

`Fin n` represents all numbers less than `n`.

But just like there is a type level equivalent of `Nat`s — `Natty`s, there is a type level equivalent of `Fin`s. But now we can incorporate value level and type level `Fin`s:

```
data Finny :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
    FZ :: Finny (S n) Z
    FS :: Finny n m -> Finny (S n) (S m)
```

The first `Nat` is an upper bound of a `Finny`. And the second `Nat` corresponds to an actual value of a `Finny`. I.e. it must be equal to `toNatFinny i`, where

```
toNatFinny :: Finny n m -> Nat
toNatFinny  FZ    = Z
toNatFinny (FS i) = S (toNatFinny i)
```

Defining the `lookup` function is now straightforward:

```
vlookup :: Finny n m -> Vec a n -> a
vlookup  FZ    (VCons x xs) = x
vlookup (FS i) (VCons x xs) = vlookup i xs
```

And some tests:

```
print $ vlookup  FZ               (VCons 1 (VCons 2 (VCons 3 VNil))) -- 1
print $ vlookup (FS FZ)           (VCons 1 (VCons 2 (VCons 3 VNil))) -- 2
print $ vlookup (FS (FS (FS FZ))) (VCons 1 (VCons 2 (VCons 3 VNil))) -- compile-time error
```

That was simple, but what about the `take` function? It's not harder:

```
type Finny0 n = Finny (S n)

vtake :: Finny0 n m -> Vec a n -> Vec a m
vtake  FZ     _           = VNil
vtake (FS i) (VCons x xs) = VCons x (vtake i xs)
```

We need `Finny0` instead of `Finny`, because `lookup` requires a `Vec` to be non-empty, so if there is a value of type `Finny n m`, then `n = S n'` for some `n'`. But `vtake FZ VNil` is perfectly valid, so we need to relax this restriction. So `Finny0 n` represents all numbers less or equal `n`.

But what about runtime data?

```
vfromList :: [a] -> (forall n. Vec a n -> b) -> b
vfromList    []  f = f VNil
vfromList (x:xs) f = vfromList xs (f . VCons x)
```

I.e. "give me a list and a function, that accepts a `Vec` of arbitrary length, and I'll apply the latter to the former". `vfromList xs` returns a continuation (i.e. something of type `(a -> r) -> r`) modulo higher-rank types. Let's try it:

```
vmhead :: Vec a n -> Maybe a
vmhead  VNil        = Nothing
vmhead (VCons x xs) = Just x

main = do
    print $ vfromList ([] :: [Int]) vmhead -- Nothing
    print $ vfromList  [1..5]       vmhead -- Just 1
```

Works. But aren't we just repeat ourself? Why `vmhead`, when there is `vhead` already? Should we rewrite all safe functions in an unsafe way to make is possible to use them on runtime data? That would be silly.

All we need is to ensure, that all invariants hold. Let's try this principle on the `vtake` function:

```
fromIntFinny :: Int -> (forall n m. Finny n m -> b) -> b
fromIntFinny 0 f = f FZ
fromIntFinny n f = fromIntFinny (n - 1) (f . FS)

main = do       
    xs <- readLn :: IO [Int]
    i <- read <$> getLine
    putStrLn $
        fromIntFinny i $ \i' ->
        vfromList xs   $ \xs' ->
        undefined -- what's here?
```

`fromIntFinny` is just like `vfromList`. It's instructive to see, what the types are:

```
i'  :: Finny n m
xs' :: Vec a p
```

But `vtake` has this type: `Finny0 n m -> Vec a n -> Vec a m`. So we need to coerce `i'`, so that it would be of type `Finny0 p m`. And also `toNatFinny i'` must be equal to `toNatFinny coerced_i'`. But this coercion is not possible in general, since if `S p < n`, then there are elements in `Finny n m`, that are not in `Finny (S p) m`, since `S p` and `n` are upper bounds.

```
coerceFinnyBy :: Finny n m -> Natty p -> Maybe (Finny0 p m)
coerceFinnyBy  FZ     p     = Just FZ
coerceFinnyBy (FS i) (Sy p) = fmap FS $ i `coerceFinnyBy` p
coerceFinnyBy  _      _     = Nothing
```

That's why there is `Maybe` here.

```
main = do       
    xs <- readLn :: IO [Int]
    i <- read <$> getLine
    putStrLn $
        fromIntFinny i $ \i' ->
        vfromList xs   $ \xs' ->
        case i' `coerceFinnyBy` vlength xs' of
            Nothing  -> "What should I do with this input?"
            Just i'' -> show $ vtoList $ vtake i'' xs'
```

In the `Nothing` case a number, that was read from the input, is bigger, than the length of a list. In the `Just` case a number is less or equal to the length of a list and coerced to the appropriate type, so `vtake i'' xs'` is well-typed.

This works, but we introduced the `coerceFinnyBy` function, that looks rather ad hoc. Decidable "less or equal" relation would be the appropriate alternative:

```
data (:<=) :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
    Z_le_Z :: Z :<= m                 -- forall n, 0 <= n
    S_le_S :: n :<= m -> S n :<= S m  -- forall n m, n <= m -> S n <= S m

type n :< m = S n :<= m

(<=?) :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Either (m :< n) (n :<= m) -- forall n m, n <= m || m < n
Zy   <=? m    = Right Z_le_Z
Sy n <=? Zy   = Left (S_le_S Z_le_Z)
Sy n <=? Sy m = either (Left . S_le_S) (Right . S_le_S) $ n <=? m
```

And a safe injecting function:

```
inject0Le :: Finny0 n p -> n :<= m -> Finny0 m p
inject0Le  FZ     _          = FZ
inject0Le (FS i) (S_le_S le) = FS (inject0Le i le)
```

I.e. if `n` is an upper bound for some number and `n <= m`, then `m` is an upper bound for this number too. And another one:

```
injectLe0 :: Finny n p -> n :<= m -> Finny0 m p
injectLe0  FZ    (S_le_S le) = FZ
injectLe0 (FS i) (S_le_S le) = FS (injectLe0 i le)
```

The code now looks like this:

```
getUpperBound :: Finny n m -> Natty n
getUpperBound = undefined

main = do
    xs <- readLn :: IO [Int]
    i <- read <$> getLine
    putStrLn $
        fromIntFinny i $ \i'  ->
        vfromList xs   $ \xs' ->
        case getUpperBound i' <=? vlength xs' of
            Left  _  -> "What should I do with this input?"
            Right le -> show $ vtoList $ vtake (injectLe0 i' le) xs'
```

It compiles, but what definition should `getUpperBound` have? Well, you can't define it. A `n` in `Finny n m` lives only at the type level, you can't extract it or get somehow. If we can't perform "downcast", we can perform "upcast":

```
fromIntNatty :: Int -> (forall n. Natty n -> b) -> b
fromIntNatty 0 f = f Zy
fromIntNatty n f = fromIntNatty (n - 1) (f . Sy)

fromNattyFinny0 :: Natty n -> (forall m. Finny0 n m -> b) -> b
fromNattyFinny0  Zy    f = f FZ
fromNattyFinny0 (Sy n) f = fromNattyFinny0 n (f . FS)
```

For comparison:

```
fromIntFinny :: Int -> (forall n m. Finny n m -> b) -> b
fromIntFinny 0 f = f FZ
fromIntFinny n f = fromIntFinny (n - 1) (f . FS)
```

So a continuation in `fromIntFinny` is universally quantified over the `n` and `m` variables, while a continuation in `fromNattyFinny0` is universally quantified over just `m`. And `fromNattyFinny0` receives a `Natty n` instead of `Int`.

There is `Finny0 n m` instead of `Finny n m`, because `FZ` is an element of `forall n m. Finny n m`, while `FZ` is not necessarily an element of `forall m. Finny n m` for some `n`, specifically `FZ` is not an element of `forall m. Finny 0 m` (so this type is uninhabited).

After all, we can join `fromIntNatty` and `fromNattyFinny0` together:

```
fromIntNattyFinny0 :: Int -> (forall n m. Natty n -> Finny0 n m -> b) -> b
fromIntNattyFinny0 n f = fromIntNatty n $ \n' -> fromNattyFinny0 n' (f n')
```

Achieving the same result, as in the @pigworker's answer:

```
unLenList :: LenList a -> (forall n. Natty n -> Vec n a -> t) -> t
unLenList (LenList xs) k = k natty xs
```

Some tests:

```
main = do
    xs <- readLn :: IO [Int]
    ns <- read <$> getLine
    forM_ ns $ \n -> putStrLn $
        fromIntNattyFinny0 n $ \n' i' ->
        vfromList xs         $ \xs'   ->
        case n' <=? vlength xs' of
            Left  _  -> "What should I do with this input?"
            Right le -> show $ vtoList $ vtake (inject0Le i' le) xs'
```

for

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[0,2,5,6,7,10]
```

returns

```
[]
[1,2]
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
What should I do with this input?
What should I do with this input?
```

The code: http://ideone.com/3GX0hd

**EDIT**

> Well, you can't define it. A n in Finny n m lives only at the type
>   level, you can't extract it or get somehow.

That's not true. Having `SingI n => Finny n m -> ...`, we can get `n` as `fromSing sing`.