# In GHC.TypeLits what is someNatVal good for (which we can't accomplish with natVal)?

Tags: haskell, types, numbers, type-level-computation

I'm trying to understand [`GHC.TypeLits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html), and specifically `someNatVal`. I understand the way it's used in this blog [post here](http://snak.tumblr.com/post/110021257487/convert-a-type-level-natural-number-to-a-value), but as mentioned the same example could have been implemented using `natVal`, like:

```
isLength :: forall len a. KnownNat len => Integer -> List len a -> Bool
isLength n _ = n == natVal (Proxy :: Proxy len)
```

Are there any uses of `someNatVal` that can't be rewritten with `natVal`?

Answer (score 4):

`SomeNat` is existentially quantified:

```
data SomeNat = forall n. KnownNat n => SomeNat (Proxy n)
```

which reads like `SomeNat` contains, well, "some `n :: Nat`". `Proxy` is a singleton that allows to lift that `n` to the type-level to satisfy the type system — in a dependently typed language we need such construction very rarely. We can define `SomeNat` in more explicit way using `GADTs`:

```
data SomeNat where
    SomeNat :: forall n. KnownNat n => Proxy n -> SomeNat
```

So `SomeNat` contains a `Nat`, which is not known statically.

Then

```
someNatVal :: Integer -> Maybe SomeNat
```

reads like "`someNatVal` receives an `Integer` and `Maybe` returns a hiden `Nat`". We can't return a `KnownNat`, because `Known` means "known at the type level", but there is nothing we know about an arbitrary `Integer` at the type level.

The inverse (modulo `SomeNat` wrapper and a `proxy` instead of the `Proxy`) of `someNatVal` is

```
natVal :: forall n proxy. KnownNat n => proxy n -> Integer
```

Reads like "`natVal` receives something that have a `Nat` in its type and returns that `Nat` converted to `Integer`".

Existentially quantified data types are usually [used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246864/3237465) for wrapping runtime values. Say you want to read a `Vec` (a list with statically known length) from `STDIN`, but how would you statically compute the length of input? There is no way. So you wrap a list, that you've read, in the corresponding existentially quantified data type, thus saying "I don't know the length, but there exists one".

However it's overkill in many cases. To do something with existentially quantified data type you need to be general: e.g. if you need to find the sum of elements of a `SomeVec` you have to define `sumVec` for `Vec`s with arbitrary length. Then you unwrap the `SomeVec` and apply `sumVec`, thus saying "I don't know the length of a wrapped `Vec`, but `sumVec` doesn't care". But instead of this wrapping-unwrapping you can [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070207/3237465) use CPS.

However because of this generality you'll need to enable [`ImpredicativeTypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092864/what-is-predicativity) to be able to define, say, a list with such continuations. In that case a list with existentially quantified data is a [common pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106169/3237465) that allows to get round `ImpredicativeTypes`.

As to your example, with properly defined `Nat`s, a version that compares `Nat`s is [lazier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020263/3237465), than a version that compares `Integer`s.

Answer (score 3):

The main use of `someNatVal` is using a value at run time as if it was a type that wasn't known at compile time.

My answer to [Can I have an unknown KnownNat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752653/can-i-have-an-unknown-knownnat/30762622#30762622) provides a really dumb example.  There are a million better ways to write a program that does the same thing as that one.  But it shows what `someNatVal` does.  It's essentially a function from value to type - with an existential limiting the scope of that type to places where it's not statically known.

Comment: I don't understand your example, or what it's intended to show. What's happening that's not happening here: `let b = Bar "foo" :: Bar n in show b`?

Comment: @jberryman The important part is where `n` comes from.  How does the type `n` come to exactly match the value provided at run time?  Types exist only at compile time in Haskell, after all. *That* is what `someNatVal` does.