# How to solve longEnough?. In Haskell

Tags: haskell

`longEnough n xs`: checks if a list has more than `n` elements.

Examples:

- `longEnough 2 [1..5] == True`
- `longEnough 3 [1,2,3] == False`
- `longEnough 0 [] == False`
- `longEnough 20 [1..] == True`

Comment: See [Is there any way to separate infinite and finite lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016410/is-there-any-way-to-separate-infinite-and-finite-lists)

Comment: Use `foldr`. Fold over the list to produce a function taking the desired strict lower length bound.

Comment: What did you try? SO is not a homework solving service. On this kind of questions, the poster is often expected to show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is homework and you are still learning the basics so I'll start by giving you some hints using the recursion instead of `foldr` (as @dfeuer proposed):

First start by noting some obvious cases:

- if `xs = []` then the result is always `False` (assuming you don't care about negative `n` in some strange ways)
- if `n = 0` and `xs` is non-empty then it's always `True`
- in all other cases you have

  - `n > 0`
  - `xs` has more than one element

Maybe you have some *recursive* idea to break the last case down?

Here is a skeleton:

```
longEnough :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
longEnough _ []     = False
longEnough 0 _      = True
longEnough n (_:xs) = let n' = (n-1) in undefined
```

For those cases - if you *look closely* you'll see that I even added more hints on the solution.

---

#### PS

- maybe you want to think about negative `n` and what should happen to those ... I did **not** here
- if you know what `foldr` is all about you should probably try to implement this using `foldr` too

---

### Solution

Seems there is no more feedback coming from the OP so I guess I can as well post the solution as I would start with:

```
longEnough :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
longEnough _ []     = False
longEnough 0 _      = True
longEnough n (_:xs) = longEnough (n-1) xs
```

(Not really much left to do...)

Here are the mentioned test-cases:

```
λ> longEnough 2 [1..5]
True
λ> longEnough 3 [1,2,3]
False
λ> longEnough 0 []
False
λ> longEnough 20 [1..]
True
```

Comment: I recommend using `=` in the explanation rather than `==`, since this probably should *not* be implemented using `==`.

Comment: @dfeuer fair point (indeed *I* did not expect to be implemented using `==` as you can see by the missing constraint)

Comment: If this weren't a homework question, `longEnough n = not . null . drop n`.