# Haskell asymptotic difference between algorithms

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, asymptotic-complexity

Here we need to get all subsequences of the given length. How to calculate the asymptotic complexity of the given function?

```
import Data.List

subsequencesOfSize l n = [x | x <- subsequences l, length x == n]
```

How many "iterations" will it be? Can we speak about "iterations". Any optimizations? GHC 7.10.2. How compiler or programmer can improve this?

Comment: Are you interested in the theoretical complexity or specifically compiled output?

Comment: Generating a huge list and then filtering out some potentially small parts from it is hardly efficient. There could be a better approach, i.e. a different algorithm, which will prune long subsequences as early as possible.

Comment: @SDmitry: reversing the argument order (i.e. `subsequencesOfSize n l`) would make for a more idiomatic design, just for the record.

Comment: It can be ineffitient if we can do it without optimisations. But it is a part of my question. Can GHC make such optimizations here after which this approach can be comparable with the early-filtering? And theoretical complexity interesting too.

Comment: along the lines of dfeuer's suggestion, you might want to check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33016778/247623 — basically you should use asomething like `lengthIsGt` to pre-filter the lists before you call `length` on them, so as to avoid evaluating very long lists. in fact, your current algorithm will loop forever if any of the lists in `l` is infinite.

Comment: I forgot about this "length" characteristic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a related SO question which discusses various implementations of `subsequencesOfSize`:

[Haskell: comparison of techniques for generating combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26727673/866915)

and the best performing one which uses memoization:

[Haskell: comparison of techniques for generating combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727673/haskell-comparison-of-techniques-for-generating-combinations/26727936#26727936)

**Update**

Also consider this version that @user3237465 mentions in the comments:

```
subsequencesOfSize :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
subsequencesOfSize n xs | n > length xs = []
subsequencesOfSize n xs = subsequencesBySize xs !! n where
    subsequencesBySize    []  = [[[]]]
    subsequencesBySize (x:xs) = zipWith (++) ([] : map (map (x:)) next) (next ++ [[]])
        where next = subsequencesBySize xs
```

Comment: There is a lazier version: compare [this](http://ideone.com/LrpZMh) and [this](http://ideone.com/ZubdHR).

Comment: Also, I think "sharing" is a more accurate term than "memoization".

Comment: @user3237465 - added your version

Answer (score 1):

I think your question contains at least 2 distinct questions, but whether (current versions of) GHC can optimize this

```
subsequencesOfSize l n = [x | x <- subsequences l, length x == n]
```

into something like

```
subsequencesOfSize l n = [x | x <- subsequences l, lengthIsGt n x, length x == n]
```

is highly doubtable — I'm nowhere near being an expert on optimization, supercompilation etc, but inferring the need for something like `lengthIsGt` from the use of `length` here seems highly non-trivial and is unlikely to be part of a compiler's set of generic optimizations.

P.S. actually the version with `lengthIsGt` will potentially still try to evaluate infinite lists if the condition containing `length` is evaluated before the condition containing `lengthIsGt` (but that was pseudocode anyway)