# Ability to get a polymorphic function from monadic action in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to be able to write an IO-action, which would return a polymorphic function, which could be used for different values, but it seems I can't. Can anyone help me doing that please?

```
f :: a -> Bool
f _ = True

getF :: Int -> (a -> Bool)
getF _ = f

getFIO :: IO (a -> Bool)
getFIO = return f

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- this works
    print ((f :: Int -> Bool) (10::Int))
    print ((f :: String -> Bool) "asd")

    -- this works
    let f' = getF 10
    print (f' (10::Int))
    print (f' "asd")

    -- this doesn't
    f'' <- getFIO
    print (f'' (10::Int))
    print (f'' "asd")

    -- but this does
    f''' <- getFIO
    print (f''' (10::Int))
    f'''' <- getFIO
    print (f'''' "asd")

    return ()
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092864/what-is-predicativity

Comment: A function of type `a -> Bool` can't do anything useful that a value of type `Bool` can't, so I'm not sure why you want to do this.

Comment: Specifically, it has to work uniformly for all choices of `a` (parametricity), so the only (defined) inhabitants are `const True` and `const False`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs it's a simplified program which reproduces error. In real-world usage, that function looks a bit different and has few type-class constraints which let you examine input-argument in many more ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell does not allow you to use a polymorphic argument to a type constructor other than `->`. You need to use a `newtype` to make use of that special exemption.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
newtype ToBool = ToBool {getToBool :: forall a . a -> Bool}

f :: ToBool
f = ToBool (const True)

getFIO :: IO ToBool
getFIO = return f
```

You'll need to apply `getToBool` each time you want to use `f`, but that's okay.

Answer (score 5):

To complement the other answers, I'd note that

```
f :: IO (a -> Bool)
```

actually means

```
f :: forall a. IO (a -> Bool)
```

which describes the following contract between caller and callee:

1. The caller chooses a type `a`
2. Then, `f` does some `IO`
3. Finally, `f` returns a value of type `a -> Bool`

Note that `a` is chosen before the IO, hence the last function is monomorphic.

Instead, we need the following type

```
f :: IO (forall a. a -> Bool)
```

which postpones the choice of `a` after the IO is done. The above type requires the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension (which does not really work at the moment in GHC), or using a `newtype` wrapper as done in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it "work" with `RankNTypes`, but then you need a newtype wrapper:

```
-- might as well be Bool
newtype Pointless = Pointless (forall a. a -> Bool)

getFIO_ :: IO Pointless
getFIO_ = return (Pointless f)

main = do
    Pointless f'' <- getFIO_
    print (f'' (10::Int))
    print (f'' "asd")
```

So you might be better off rearranging your program to not use that extension, by changing `getFIO :: IO Blah`, defining a `applyBlah :: Blah -> a -> Bool`, and then using `applyBlah f''` where you previously had `f''`.