# Pattern matching inferred type

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, higher-rank-types

Why doesn't the below type-check? The type of `_` is inferred as Double.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, Rank2Types #-}

module Main (main) where

data D a = D a

main =
  let
    n = D (1 :: forall a. (Floating a) => a)
  in
    case n of
      D (_ :: forall a. (Floating a) => a) -> return ()
```

Comment: Haskell does not support types like `D (forall a. (Floating a) => a)`, which is the type it looks like you actually want for `n` here, because that would require impredicative polymorphism. While `1` is indeed polymorphic here, `D 1` still defaults to `D Double` due to Haskell’s type defaulting rules (otherwise the type would be considered ambiguous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the type you are expecting for `n` is `D (forall a. (Floating a) => a)`, but that is emphatically *not* the type that is inferred. In fact, if you try and add that type annotation to `n`, you will find that GHC will loudly complain. Such a type would require GHC to support impredicative polymorphism, and it currently does not (for more information on what that is and why it is complicated, see [What is predicativity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092864/what-is-predicativity)).

The type that is actually inferred for `n` is `D Double`. This is actually the result of two things at play: the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction) and Haskell’s type defaulting rules. Due to the monomorphism restriction, `n` must be inferred to be a monomorphic type (since it is not syntactically a function and does not have an explicit type annotation). For this reason, `D 1` would be ambiguous, since `1 :: forall a. (Floating a) => a` is polymorphic. However, in this case, Haskell has defaulting rules for numeric types, mostly to avoid the need to resolve ambiguities due to Haskell’s polymorphic number literals.

Since you have explicitly added a type annotation to `1` to make it `Floating`, then Haskell applies its default rule for floating-point types and defaults to `Double`. Therefore, the type of `n` is inferred to be `D Double`.

If you disable the monomorphism restriction, then the type of `n` would be the slightly more interesting type `forall a. Floating a => D a`, but that is the simpler universally quantified type rather than the existentially quantified one that you want.