# Eliminating phantom types in a list

Tags: haskell, phantom-types

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to run computations in the ST monad on a list.

```
import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad.ST

makeST :: Int -> ST s Int
makeST x = do
    r <- newSTRef x
    readSTRef r

main :: IO [Int]
main = pure $ map runST sts
  where sts = map makeST [0..5]
```

But trying to compile this gives the following error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘ST s0 Int’ with ‘forall s. ST s Int’
      Expected type: ST s0 Int -> Int
        Actual type: (forall s. ST s Int) -> Int
    • In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘runST’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘map runST sts’
      In the expression: pure $ map runST sts
```

If I were running this in the IO monad, this would be a simple matter of replacing `pure . map runST` with `traverse runIO` (or whatever), but I haven't figured out how to get around the presence of the phantom type parameter. I suspect the list `sts` needs to have different type parameters for the different list elements, and hence needs to be a heterogeneous list of some persuation, but wrapping the ST monads just introduces a new error in addition to the old one.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype WrappedST = WrappedST { unwrap :: forall s. ST s Int }

main :: IO [Int]
main = pure $ map (runST . unwrap) sts
  where sts = map (WrappedST . makeST) [0..5]
```

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘ST s1 Int’ with ‘forall s. ST s Int’
      Expected type: ST s1 Int -> WrappedST
        Actual type: (forall s. ST s Int) -> WrappedST
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘WrappedST’
      In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(WrappedST . makeST)’
      In the expression: map (WrappedST . makeST) [0 .. 5]
```

What is the best way to handle this issue, where the phantom type variables are eliminated by a function `runST` and so should be unifiable, but I'm having trouble convincing the typechecker of that?

Note: The actual example I'm trying to figure out involves the R monad in the `inline-r` package, which also has a phantom type and is eliminated with the function `runRegion :: NFData a => (forall s. R s a) -> IO a`. I believe this example in the ST monad should also capture the root problem here, and is more widely known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is good enough:

```hs
import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad.ST

makeST :: Int -> ST s Int
makeST x = do
    r <- newSTRef x
    readSTRef r

main :: IO [Int]
main = pure $ runST (mapM makeST [0..5])
```

In short, don't store `ST` actions in a list; instead, use an `ST` action to compute a list.

If that isn't good enough for some reason (what reason?), then simply delta-expanding the `(.)`s in your second example lets it compile:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad.ST

makeST :: Int -> ST s Int
makeST x = do
    r <- newSTRef x
    readSTRef r

newtype WrappedST = WrappedST { unwrap :: forall s. ST s Int }

main :: IO [Int]
main = pure $ map (\x -> runST (unwrap x)) sts
  where sts = map (\x -> WrappedST (makeST x)) [0..5]
```

Comment: That second option is rather eager. What's wrong with running the `ST` actions individually to make the list elements?

Comment: `main = pure $ map (\n -> runST (makeST n)) [0..5] runST sts`

Comment: @dfeuer That raises an interesting question, is `WrappedST` (or it's parametrized variant `WrappedST a`) isomorphic to `Int` (`a`) as witnessed by `runST` and `return`? I would guess so, in which case there should never be a reason to choose the answer's `WrappedST` over just using `runST` immediately like you did.

Comment: @HTNW, that's an interesting question. At first I thought yes, but now I'm less sure, especially with regard to strictness. You can do `unwrapST m >>= unwrapST . f`, and I'm not sure where that leaves you.

Comment: @dfeuer But the two unwrappings can't share any mutable state, or else they wouldn't be able to be typed as `forall s.`'s. ...right?

Comment: @HTNW, my bet is that `WrappedST a` is morally equivalent to `a`, but is more precisely equivalent to `(##) -> (# a #)` once strictness details are taken into account.

Comment: @DanielWagner, correct. The tricky bit is the relationship in the definedness lattice. `runST` collapses a little bit too much. Consider instead `runST# :: (forall a. ST s a) -> (# a #); runST# (ST m) = runRW# (\s -> case m s of (# _, a #) -> (# a #))`.

Comment: Or, more user-friendly, `runSTA :: Applicative f => (forall a. ST s a) -> f a; runSTA (ST m) = runRW# (\s -> case m s of (# _, a #) -> pure a)`.

Comment: I was vaguely aware that eta reduction could interfere with type inference, but this was the first time I've seen it in the wild. Do you in which situations I should be looking for this sort of solution to fix type inference?

Comment: @StephenMorgan You must avoid passing polymorphic things to functions when retaining that polymorphism is important and would require instantiating a type variable with a `forall` type. In this case, you are passing the polymorphic `makeST` to `(.)`; the polymorphism is important because `runST` demands polymorphism; and the `b` in `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` would have to be instantiated with a `forall` type to retain that polymorphism. See also [runST and function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9468963) and [What is predicativity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33092864).